# How to run FastAPI in shell mode?

Tags: python, shell, fastapi

I want to execute FastAPI in shell.
For example, we can do it with the below code in Django:

```
python manage.py shell
```

How can I do this in FastAPI?

Comment: Seeing three answers (some deleted) suggesting to use uvicorn to run the fastapi program, maybe you should be more clear what you mean by "run from terminal" or "execute in shell" here. It seems you want some sort of interactive session, but that's impossible to know if you don't know Django.

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer, **You can not.**

`manage.py` does the same thing as django-admin but also sets the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable so that it points to your project’s settings.py file. In FastAPI we don't have admin utility, because there is no out-of-box config, environment management etc. That's the main difference between a microframework and a high-level framework.

FastAPI does not have any administration utilities out-of-box.

Comment: `manage.py shell` won't run a *"development server"* in Django

Comment: Did you even read the question? `manage.py shell` starts interactive interpreter, we do not have any of Django's features so i  can not run any of them, exactly what you are expecting to see from my example?

Comment: Yes, I read. The statement *"...execute fastapi in shell"* makes sense but, the example ( example ***like*** `python manage.py shell` in Django) doesn't fit in this context, because on running the command `python manage.py shell`, Django won't start the server, but only an interactive shell which is not in your example. @Yagizcan Degirmenci

Comment: I would say, your answer is a perfect fit for the OP unless there is no mentioning of the `python manage.py shell` command. The OP is not much clear about ***running the server*** or ***an interactive session***

Comment: @ArakkalAbu While I agree the OP's wording is somewhat ambiguous, IMO it pretty clearly boils down to "what is the equivalent of `manage.py shell` in fastapi", without any context about the dev server.

Comment: @YagizDegirmenci Let me suggest to replace the "you can not" notion with an explaination why something simple like `python -i app.py` will achieve exactly the same given the absence of framework-specific initialization stuff.

Answer (score 2):

In terminal go to directory where your main.py is and type

```
uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8888
```

Comment: This command starts a server in FastAPI.. not an interactive session..

Comment: Apparently, you haven't understood quite well the question!

Answer (score -1):

[image]You cannot do that, But by running `python` in the terminal and importing proper functions and packages you can do most of the essential tasks like debugging your function

Comment: Please [don't post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score -1):

You can use debug console offerd by your IDE, if you're using VScode you can simple configure your `launch.json` like:

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "FastApi Server",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "module": "uvicorn",
        "args": [
            "main:app",
            "--reload"
        ],
        "jinja": true,
        "justMyCode": false
    }
]
```

Comment: This doesn't give you a shell, which is probably what OP wants.

Comment: Thank you for the comment cause now i understand better the questione, actually i think he can use a shell configuring a session with pycharm or vscode

Comment: @AKX I modify my Answer!

Comment: Great - it still doesn't give OP a shell.